# How can I read client-side chat input without actually sending a message in chat?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to make a fairly simple mod that reads the user's chat input and then changes the actual message sent with based on commands. Essentially it takes a message and uses a specific rgb format to make the text appear rainbow. It's very similar to sign text formatting. The issue is that I cannot for the life of me find a way to read chat input (or send messages, but I suspect fixing the 1st problem will also fix this one).

Right now, I've tried using the [Forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/) mdk, but it doesn't seem to include a way to read chat messages. I only stumbled across forge thanks to a youtube tutorial, but no matter which way i word the search, google and youtube aren't showing me actual results because "minecraft chat mod" or the like shows me all the "latest and greatest" commands instead of what i'm actually looking for.

Help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like a fool for not being able to figure this out.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, please? Are you looking to make a plugin, datapack or something?

Comment: @JessyGuirado Is that better? Sorry, first time using StackOverflow

Comment: Yes, however. I sadly mainly do plugins and not mods. But, I know for sure that mods got events (but I'm not sure of that) try to look into some kind of chat events to gather the input of the user and then handle it. In plugins, for example, we got the AsyncPlayerChatEvent which triggers every time a player sends something in chat. Maybe that can help you!